# Scatterplot with x-axis and y-axis values dependent on column values, each axis measures same variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tibble, geom-point

I have a tibble `df` that looks like this:

```
        id       sex     rating
1       43      male         10
2       44    female          8
3       45      male          7
4       46      male          3
5       47    female          5
```

How would I go about using `ggplot2` to represent this data on a scatterplot with one dot for each `id`, female ratings on the y-axis, and male ratings on the x-axis? Do I have to modify `df` before using `geom_point()`? Or without modifying `df`, how could I set `aes(x = ..., y = ...)` within `geom_point()`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = rating) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = male, y = female)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: It's not clear from your example data, but presumably each id has exactly one male and one female rating?